# NOOB question problem nesting content_tag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, content-tag

I have the following in my view

```
<%= content_tag :p, :class => "title-choose" do %>
         Select image or 
            <%=content_tag :div, :class =>"inputReplacement" do %>
                <%= form_for @upload, :remote => true, :html => { :multipart => true, :method => :post, :id => 'uploadForm', :class => "hiddenInput", :size => 13 } do |f| %>
                    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
                <% end %>
                add image from your computer:
            <% end %>
        <% end%>
```

Which produces the following html:

```
<p class="title-choose"> Select image or </p>
<div class="inputReplacement">
<form id="uploadForm" class="hiddenInput" size="13" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-remote="true" action="/uploads" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<input id="upload_photo" type="file" name="upload[photo]">
</form>
add image from your computer:
</div>
<p></p>
```

Which is not what i want. I want the div wrapped in the p.

Anyone know how to do this with content_tag?

Thanks

Mitch

Comment: why not just do plain html or haml? also, semantically, the p should be the one enclosed by the div :)

Comment: You are right about the div in a p. I will correct that. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: also try not using content tag since it looks like you're in an erb template. normal html tags work there. only use content tags in helpers

Comment: @corroded: using `content_tag`s in erb templates is actually encouraged instead of using plain html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I paste your view code into my Rails 3.0.7 application view (`index.html.erb` -- the naming is important) I have this nested properly:

```
<p class="title-choose">
         Select image or 
            <div class="inputReplacement">
                <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/globalize/translations" class="hiddenInput" data-remote="true" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm" method="post" size="13"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="f9/6FmfCO7ezrhaUMOp+d7xOti+6UcvgzQq7M5u9HFU=" /></div>
                    <input id="globalize_translation_photo" name="globalize_translation[photo]" type="file" />
</form>                add image from your computer:
</div></p>
```

Just don't mind that my `@upload` object is different.

And yes, you really should nest `<p>` tags inside `<div>`s, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pewel I will try to change the formatting so the p is not inside the div. Actually its the front end people I have to talk to so I will take your advice.